# Error with centering a marker based on my own location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to center a marker on a user location(geolocation), but i have been having error of this type: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPosition' of undefined at showPosition** . What have i been missing or doing wrong? I hope someone can help me out.
This is my javascript code:

```
var map;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var x = document.getElementById("geoLocation");
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}
function showPosition(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('This is your location.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + (position.coords.latitude).toFixed(6) + 
"<br>Longitude: " + (position.coords.longitude).toFixed(6);
}


  function initMap() {
    var bamako = new google.maps.LatLng(12.6425212, -8.0099928),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: bamako,
      zoom: 16
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: bamako, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousemove", function (e) {
    var t = e.latLng;
    document.getElementById("mlat").innerHTML = "(" + t.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + t.lng().toFixed(6) + ")"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
    marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
    var t = e.latLng, o = "(" + t.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + t.lng().toFixed(6) + ")";
    document.getElementById("lat").value = t.lat().toFixed(6), document.getElementById("lng").value = t.lng().toFixed(6);
    });
    getLocation();
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geolocation</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>MaliBaGuide</title>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 80%;
    width: 70%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="getLocation()">Get My 
Position</button>
<h6>GeoLocation Coordinates</h6>
<div id="geoLocation"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
  <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" placeholder="lat coordinate" />
  <label for="lng">Longitude</label>
  <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" placeholder="long coordinate" />
  <h3 class="titleh3">Map Mouse Over Location</h3>
  <span id="mlat" class="coordinatetxt">0,0</span>
</div>
<script src="gmap1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=AIzaSyCXZ1ps6lHbElohymJukUi4KOY6g_rjGQ0&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what the `var infoWindow` should be? an object or a reference to a plugin or what? the problem is that `infoWindow` is not initialized as a valid object, it's just created like this: `var infoWindow;`, so it has no value, no reference, no nothing

Comment: I am trying to attach the infoWindow to the marker based on the user location

Comment: `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();` what about checking the [very basic official examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)?

Comment: I just did initialize it the way you suggested but still throwing same error

Answer (score 0):

It means you haven't actually set `infoWindow` to be anything, you've just declared that it exists. The JavaScript interpreter is telling you that you can't try to access a property for something that hasn't itself been defined yet.

You can initialize `infoWindow` properly by instantiating it as follows:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
```

Full code (with some cleaned-up formatting):

```
var map;
var infoWindow;
var x = document.getElementById("geoLocation");

function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
}

function showPosition(position) {
        var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('This is your location.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + (position.coords.latitude).toFixed(6) + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + (position.coords.longitude).toFixed(6);
}


function initMap() {
    var bamako = new google.maps.LatLng(12.6425212, -8.0099928),
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: bamako,
                zoom: 16
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: bamako, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousemove", function (e) {
                var t = e.latLng;
                document.getElementById("mlat").innerHTML = "(" + t.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + t.lng().toFixed(6) + ")"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
                marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
                var t = e.latLng, o = "(" + t.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + t.lng().toFixed(6) + ")";
                document.getElementById("lat").value = t.lat().toFixed(6), document.getElementById("lng").value = t.lng().toFixed(6);
    });
    getLocation();
}
```

Comment: How do i set it?

Comment: @sankareb I think someone else has already answered that in comments but for clarity I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: I just did initialize it the way you suggested but still throwing same error.

Comment: @sankareb please update your question with the _exact_ code you're now using so I can take a look at it.

Comment: @sankareb is the error exactly the same or is it slightly different?

Comment: @sankareb I've updated my example - you need to pass at least an empty JSON object into the `InfoWindow` call and then it should work. I downloaded your code and tested it on my local machine and verified that should work. So just do `new google.maps.InfoWindow({})` instead of what I suggested earlier. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Still same problem!
Can you please upload the modified code that worked for you on your local machine?

Comment: @sankareb I've updated my answer with the code, but I really only changed that one thing.

Comment: It still not working for me. Now it's saying google is not defined at line 2, i.e. the change you made... Appreciate your effort though!

Comment: I am pretty certain google was never defined. I got two error messages with your original code, not one.

Comment: Okay so to fix the google error you need to move the initialization into your callback function. So you could do ‘var InfoWindow’ the way you did originally and then within ‘initMap’ you’d set InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}). That should fix it.

Comment: @sankareb I updated my answer with the full code that should have no errors.